# Restore horizontal scroll position in TDBGrid

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

I wrote a simple method to sort column in TDBGrid.
If Option.RowSelect set to False everything works fine, but if RowSelect gets True the horizontal position scroll doesn't restore after sort column.
So I try GetScrollPos and SetScrollPos to restore horizontal Scroll position, the ScrollBar goes to the right position but TDBGrid didn't scroll, here is the method:

```
procedure TDBGrid.TitleClick(Column: TColumn);
var
  CurrenctPosition: TBookmark;
  PosScroll: Integer;
begin
  inherited TitleClick(Column);
  if FAllowTitleClick and (Assigned(DataSource))
  and (Assigned(DataSource.DataSet))
  and (DataSource.DataSet.Active)
  and (Assigned(Column.Field))
  and (Column.Field.FieldKind <> fkLookup) then
  begin
    //Get position scroll
    PosScroll := GetScrollPos(Handle, SB_HORZ);
    CurrenctPosition := DataSource.DataSet.GetBookmark;
    FPaintInfo.ColPressed := False;
    FPaintInfo.ColPressedIdx := -1;
    if ValidCell(FCell) then
      InvalidateCell(FCell.X, FCell.Y);
    SortColumn(Column);
    DataSource.DataSet.GotoBookmark(CurrenctPosition);
    //Set position scroll
    SetScrollPos(Handle, SB_HORZ, PosScroll, True);//<- need to be refreshed
  end;
end;
```

This can maybe fixed using Perform(WM_HSCROLL, SB_LINERIGHT, 0) in loop but isn't good idea.
Anybody have better solution?

Comment: why don't you just use TSMDBGrid?

Comment: Maybe because it's not free? This is clearly something that should be possible in TDBGrid, so IMHO there's no reason to give up and use another (commercial) component...

Comment: @eKek0
TSMDBGrid nice free component, but this one is small, easy and faster and it does exactly the job.
@Smasher
...In may Opinion TSMDBGrid is free, and this is modified version of TThemedDBGrid, you can get it (free) here:
http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=206

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a way to control what is the leftmost column:

```
type
  TGridFriend=class(TDBGrid);


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // scroll to right by one column
  TGridFriend(DBGrid1).leftCol:=TGridFriend(DBGrid1).leftCol + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks X-Ray, simple and working idea.
Just save last LeftCol and restore it after making a sort.

Answer (score 0):

You might find an answer here:

http://www.species.net/Aves/Cassowary/delphi.htm

Look for "SetScrollPos" in the text.

Maybe ModifyScrollBar(Code, SB_THUMBPOSITION, Value) holds the solution.